# How to sort list of strings of numbers in c#

Tags: c#, list

I have a function in c# which runs async with treads and adds buildnumbers to a list. All the buildnumbers comes in different orders but i would like to sort them to get the highest build numbers forst and lowest last. I have tryed using.

> .sort()

And

> .Reverse();

But i still dont get them in the correct order.

Here is a picture from my debug which shows you how they acctually sory but not in the correct order.

[image: Image of list of build numbers]

Thanks in advance.

This is the method which creates the list.

```csharp
private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> RetrieveBuildNumbers(string project, string iteration)
{
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
    List<string> dataToReturn = new List<string>();
    IEnumerable<IBuild> builds = GetBuilds(project);
    //We do "-4" to sort only on the last 4 digits in iteration name "23.0"
    string buildVersion = iteration.Substring(iteration.Length - 4);

    var tasks = new List<Task>(200);
    var lockOfDeath = new object();
    foreach (IBuild build in builds)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {

            if (build.BuildNumber.Contains(buildVersion.ToLower()))
            {
                ITestRuns testRuns = TS.Runs.TSRuns.GetTestRunByBuildUriWithDetails(project, build.Uri, includeRunDetails: true);
                IEnumerable<ITestRun> sortTestRuns = testRuns.Value.Where(p => p.Build.Id == build.Id);

                foreach (ITestRun testRun in sortTestRuns)
                {
                    lock (lockOfDeath)
                    {
                        // Add only the same build number once
                        if (dataToReturn.FirstOrDefault(p => p == build.BuildNumber) == null)
                        {
                            dataToReturn.Add(build.BuildNumber);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    //List<string> 
    dataToReturn.Sort();
    dataToReturn.Reverse();
    return dataToReturn.OrderByDescending(p => p);
}
```

Comment: Are these version numbers?

Comment: Yes these are version numbers

Comment: @KristoferMarEinarsson just in case you didn't notice, the accepted answer in the duplicate was doing more then just Sort() and Reverse().  it was using the Version object which can actually sort these types of number, where as if they are strings they can't.

Comment: Here [Version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx) class. In the duplicate you have `new List<Version>()` and `new Version("3.5")`. It's a build in C# class.

Comment: Ok thank you for telling me @Richardissimo